# UI bug when changing "View as: iPhone" in storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode9, xcode-storyboard

I got a storyboard with many view controllers. If I select for exemple, "view as iPhone SE" and build to an iPhone SE everything is ok. But if I keep "View as iPhone SE" and build to an iPhone 6, the UI is buggy. This can be reproduce for every iPhone. I'm using auto-layout and constraints.

I tried to archive and upload to test flight but I got the same issue.

Comment: You should use auto-resizing or constraints for solving the ui issue.

Comment: I'm using constraints

Comment: Then the possible reason must be you are not applying the constraints properly. Would you please upload any screenshot, So that the question is more understandable.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnthoPak Yes, I just wrote my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because I was doing some UI changes in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` functions.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I was adding rounded corners in `viewDidLoad`. But making changes in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead wasn't the best option, as it will get called multiple times, and the frame is sometimes wrong on first call (since Xcode 8…). So my solution is to call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` just before making changes (in `viewDidLoad`). +1 because you lead me on the right track :)

Comment: Yes I'm agree it's why I had a boolean drawer = false, init to true if the view was draw one time. In my case it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

From Storyboard, open up Assistant Editor.

From the Assistant Editor menu, choose Preview.

Current active view controller will be displayed in the Assistant Editor.

Add several phone with different sizes so that you can see autolayout result real time without the need to build on simulator.

[image]